# How to give a geometric interpretation of linear system which has four vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

[image]

I figured out the solution with 2 independent variables and 2 free variables

The solution set is:
$$[x,y,z,w]=[10,23,0,0]+t[-1,1,1,0]+s[3/2,11/2,0,1]$$

However, how to give a geometric interpretation for this solution?
Thanks

Comment: It's just a plane, in 4D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The set you are referring to is the linear span of two linearly independent vectors, hence it is of dimension $2$, in a space of dimension $4$. Such an object is what we would describe as a $4$-line geometrically, which means it is a $2$ dimensional object embedded in a space of dimension $4$. It's relation with respect to space, will be the same as the relation between a normal line and $3$ dimensions, in that it will extend in all basis directions except two. So it would be a plane, extending in two directions, but it would leave two directions out instead of one.

In general, an $m-2$ dimensional object embedded in $m$ dimensional space is called an $m$-line.

Comment: The equations aren't linearly independent.  $3R_1 - R_2 = R_3$.  In this case, the solution set refers to a regular $2$d plane.

Comment: Source for the term "$4$-line"?

Comment: @Bye_World Thank you I actually realized it just afterwards, I was searching for the terminology for the embedding of the object, so I did not edit it early enough. The source for the term $4-line$ is from a friend of mine, who is next to me. He says he found it in some textbook on geometry, by Hardy or somebody. It's old-terminology.